# Jquery changing css class on checkbox change

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I've put some jQuery together to change the highlighting on a container (default red, black on check) when a specific checkbox is checked. I feel this code could be simplified, but not sure how. Does anyone have any ideas please?

```
$("#container input:checkbox[id=cbTermsAndConditions]").change(function() {
   if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
     $('#container').addClass("containerblack");
     $('#container').removeClass("containerred");
   } else {
     $(this).parent().addClass("containerred");
     $(this).parent().removeClass("containerblack");
   }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little cleaner:

```
$("#container input:checkbox[id=cbTermsAndConditions]").click(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   if ($this.attr("checked")) {
     $('#container').toggleClass("containerblack containerred");
   } else {
     $this.parent().toggleClass("containerred containerblack");
   }
});
```

Also, you could get the "checked" value with raw javascript, replacing the if statement with:

```
if(this.checked)
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know you could toggle more than one css class. I have also changed to using this.checked. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Use the click event as the value of checkbox does not change and you can probably use toggle class if all you are doing is adding and removing classes.